# How to configure Struts 2 to find 'action results' from both classpath and WEB-INF?

Tags: struts2, freemarker

**Background**

We have an existing webapp, built with Struts 2 and Freemarker, of which I’ve created a variation by copying some of the code and templates.  Kludgy, but manageable.  We will however soon be making quite a few other variants (which need to be individual WARs), making copying untenable.  My thought is to instead put all the shared stuff into a jar included with each webapp:  the common files could be maintained in one place, and even better a given webapp could override files from the classpath.   So far I've been able to do this with the code, but the Convention plugin is making it difficult to do the same for the Freemarker templates.

**Problem**

Thus far our webapp has relied on Convention to find the Freemarker “action results” (i.e. templates) for actions at application start-up, saving us from having to tediously annotate each of them.   If I've traced things correctly, the class `DefaultResultMapBuilder` is responsible for finding the actions results; in particular, the method `createFromResources` looks in the webapp and then on the classpath for template files matching our actions.

This is exactly what I want – except that we put our templates under `/WEB-INF` to protect them from outside access (using the `struts.convention.result.path` constant in our Struts configuration).   This has worked fine until now, with ALL template files located under `/WEB-INF`, but it’s not working with files also on the classpath.   `DefaultResultMapBuilder` can certainly find files on the classpath, but only when webapp templates are under the context root directly, as any classpath templates have to be in a package structure equivalent to the directory structure of templates under the context root.   For action results to be found when “struts.convention.result.path" starts with “/WEB-INF/” would require a root package called “web-inf” – but of course hyphens are not allowed in package names.

*(Note that this issue is independent of the `TemplateLoader` classes that are later used to actually grab the template files.   The loading process is readily configurable to look in many places – but the app never gets that far if the ‘action results’ are not found at startup.  It would be nice if both processes used the same configuration...)*

**Solutions?**

So… I could move all our templates outside of `/WEB-INF` but really I’d rather not.   Or I could provide specific annotations for each action class, and again I’d rather not (and indeed it might suffer from the same issue).

Or I could make my own implementation of `ResultMapBuilder` by copying and very slightly changing `DefaultResultMapBuilder` (every member in the latter is private, so I can't extend the class and change just the relevant parts – alas!), and then figure out how to override the "struts-plugin.xml" Struts config file (to change the `org.apache.struts2.convention.ResultMapBuilder` bean), and thus I could get Convention to ignore "/WEB-INF" when looking on the classpath.  Or perhaps better, to always prefix the path with "/WEB-INF/" when looking in the ServletContext.

But maybe there's an easier way?   Some undocumented bit of configuration magic?